# R Report Anova for scientific papers

Tags: anova, reporting

How do you report ANOVA for thesis or Papers from R? My question is for the degree of freedom. Here is one picture from SPSS I guess
[image]

But in R it looks different, is it the same?:

[image]

Comment: yes, they are the same, $F(3, 58)=39.82, p < .001$

Comment: In paper or thesis do you have to report the exact p value or can you stick to the minimum alpha level like you did ?

Comment: How low you go before you report a p value as an inequality depends on the convention in your field. My choice of .001 has nothing to do with alpha levels.